# causes of seg fault in fortran

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I want to find out all eigenvalues and relevant right eigenvectors using lapack. However, the code could just work in small matrix size. While the size of my matrix is over some specific number like 300, it collapsed and all I got is segmentation fault (core dumped). I checked my code several times and still could not find out where the problem is. Following is my code.

```
program Eigenvalue
! finding the eigenvalues of a complex matrix using LAPACK
! http://www.netlib.org/lapack/complex16/zgeev.f
!find out the inverse complex matrix in fortran


Implicit none
!matrix dimension
integer, parameter::N=300
integer,parameter::M=3*(N-1)
! declarations, notice double precision
! A and B are matrices with given value while inver is inverse matrix of A
! S is to check whether inverse matrix is right or not        

real*8,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::A
real*8,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::Inver
real*8,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::B
real*8,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::S
!Mul is the matrix to be calculated in the subroutine and its values are
!product of inverse matrix and B
!eigval represents eigenvalues while Vec are eigenvectors
complex*16,allocatable,dimension(:,:):: Mul,DUMMY,Vec
complex*16,allocatable,dimension(:)::eigval,WORK1
double precision::WORK2(2*M)

integer i,j,ok,temp,error

!specific parameters in this case to define A and B 

real*8 ky,k,lb,ln,kz,ni,to
real*8 x,dx
real*8::x0=-30.d0,x1=30.d0
real*8 co1,co2,co3,co4

allocate(A(M,M),B(M,M),Inver(M,M),S(M,M),stat=error)
if (error.ne.0)then
  print *,"error:not enough memory"
  stop
end if

allocate(Mul(M,M),DUMMY(M,M),Vec(M,M),eigval(M),WORK1(2*M),stat=error)
if (error.ne.0)then
  print *,"error:not enough memory"
  stop
end if
!values of parameters 

ni=5
to=1
ln=10.d0
lb=50.d0
ky=0.4d0
kz=0.002d0
k=(1.d0+ni)/to
dx=(x1-x0)/N
x=x1-dx
co1=(1+ky*ky)*dx*dx-2
co2=ky*(-2*k+(1-k*ky*ky)*dx*dx)
co3=dx*dx*(kz-ky*(x/lb)**2)
co4=ky*k
call mkl_set_num_threads( 2  )

!definition of the initial matrix A

do i=1,M
  do j=1,N-1
        if(j.eq.i)then
        A(i,j)=-2+(1+ky*ky)*dx*dx
        else if (j.eq.(i+1)) then
        A(i,j)=-1
        else if (j.eq.(i-1).and.j.ne.(N-1)) then
        A(i,j)=-1
        else if(j.eq.(i-1).and.j.eq.(N-1))then
         A(i,j)=0
        else
        A(i,j)=(0,0)
        end if
   end do
   do j=N,M
       if(j.eq.i)then
        A(i,j)=1
       else
        A(i,j)=0
       end if
   end do
 end do
call inverse(A,Inver,M)
!definition of matrix B and the multiplication Mul

do i=1,M
      do j=1,N-1
        if(j.eq.i)then
        B(i,j)=ky*((1-k*ky*ky)*dx*dx-2*k)
        else if (j.eq.(i+1)) then
        B(i,j)=ky*k
        else if (j.eq.(i-1).and.j.ne.(N-1)) then
        B(i,j)=ky*k
        else if (j.eq.(i-1).and.j.eq.(N-1))then
        B(i,j)=0
        else if(j.eq.(i-N+1)) then
        B(i,j)=kz-((x0+j*dx)**2)*ky/(lb*lb)
        else if (j.eq.(i-2*N+2)) then
        B(i,j)=k*ky
        else
        B(i,j)=0
        end if
      end do
      do j=N,2*(N-1)
       if(j.eq.(i+N-1))then
        B(i,j)=(kz-((x0+i*dx)**2)*ky/(lb*lb))*dx*dx
       else
        B(i,j)=0
       end if
      end do
      do j=2*N-1,M
        if(j.eq.(i+N-1)) then
         B(i,j)=kz-((x0+(i-N+1)*dx)**2)*ky/(lb*lb)
        else
         B(i,j)=0
      end if
      end do
end do

Mul=matmul(Inver,B)
call ZGEEV('N', 'V', M,Mul, M, eigval, DUMMY, M, Vec, M, WORK1, 2*M, WORK2, ok)
deallocate(A,B,Inver,S,stat=error)
if (error.ne.0)then
  print *,"error:fail to release"
  stop
end if
deallocate(Mul,DUMMY,Vec,eigval,WORK1,stat=error)
if (error.ne.0)then
  print *,"error:failed to release"
  stop
end if
end
subroutine inverse(a,c,n)

!============================================================ 
! Inverse matrix
! Method: Based on Doolittle LU factorization for Ax=b
! Alex G. December 2009
!this is for real numbers
!-----------------------------------------------------------
! input ...
! a(n,n) - array of coefficients for matrix A
! n      - dimension
! output ...
! c(n,n) - inverse matrix of A
! comments ...
! the original matrix a(n,n) will be destroyed 
! during the calculation
!===========================================================

implicit none
integer n
double precision a(n,n), c(n,n)
double precision,allocatable,dimension(:,:):: L, U
double precision,allocatable,dimension(:):: b, d, x
double precision coeff
integer i, j, k,error

allocate(L(n,n),U(n,n),b(n),d(n),x(n),stat=error)
 if (error.ne.0)then
  print *,"error:not enough memory"
  stop
 end if

! step 0: initialization for matrices L and U and b
! Fortran 90/95 allows such operations on matrices

L=0.0
U=0.0
b=0.0

! step 1: forward elimination

do k=1, n-1
 do i=k+1,n
  coeff=a(i,k)/a(k,k)
  L(i,k) = coeff
  do j=k+1,n
     a(i,j) = a(i,j)-coeff*a(k,j)
  end do
 end do
end do

! Step 2: prepare L and U matrices 
! L matrix is a matrix of the elimination coefficient
! + the diagonal elements are 1.0

do i=1,n
  L(i,i) = 1.0
end do
! U matrix is the upper triangular part of A

do j=1,n
  do i=1,j
   U(i,j) = a(i,j)
  end do
end do

! Step 3: compute columns of the inverse matrix C

do k=1,n
  b(k)=1.0
  d(1) = b(1)
! Step 3a: Solve Ld=b using the forward substitution

  do i=2,n
    d(i)=b(i)
    do j=1,i-1
      d(i) = d(i) - L(i,j)*d(j)
    end do
  end do
! Step 3b: Solve Ux=d using the back substitution

  x(n)=d(n)/U(n,n)
  do i = n-1,1,-1
    x(i) = d(i)
    do j=n,i+1,-1
     x(i)=x(i)-U(i,j)*x(j)
    end do
  x(i) = x(i)/u(i,i)
  end do
! Step 3c: fill the solutions x(n) into column k of C

 do i=1,n
  c(i,k) = x(i)
 end do
  b(k)=0.0
end do
  deallocate(L,U,b,d,x,stat=error)
if (error.ne.0)then
  print *,"error:failed to deallocate"
  stop
end if
end subroutine inverse
```

Hope someone can give me a tip or advice about why the segmentation fault occurs when N is 
over 300.

Comment: sorry, I mean size of matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to ZGEEV, could it be that the dimension of `WORK1` (argument after `WORK1`) is incorrect, shouldn't it be `2*M` instead of `3*M`? Also, `WORK2` should be a double precision array.

With the updated information, the problem seems to be in the `inverse` subroutine. It's a combination of using automatic arrays, and the fact that the Intel compiler puts all automatic arrays on the stack. With large numbers for `n`, `L` and `U` together take up almost 16 MB on the stack. You can either not use automatic arrays, or compile with the option `-heap-arrays`. ALternatively, on linux, you can use `ulimit -s unlimited` to allow for unlimited stack size.

Comment: sorry to make so simple mistakes. I rewrote as you said. Still, the fault occurs. Is there anything that could cause a segmentation fault?

Comment: Hi, then please, update the question according to your actual current source code, so people can continue to help you.

Comment: thanks very much. I just posted all code just now. waiting for your advice.

Comment: following up on the answer of M.S.B., you should first compile with e.g. `-fbounds-check` and `-ggdb` if you use `gfortran`, so you can find out where exactly the seg. fault happens. So, please also list compiler used and any flags.

Comment: I'm using ifortran, is there any compile detection?

Comment: if you use `ifort` (never heard of ifortran?) then you should use the flags `-traceback -debug -check bounds`, this will enable a stacktrace at runtime at the point of failure.

Comment: got it. I think ifortran is the short name of intel fortran? ifort is the command of calling ifortran? anyway, i'm trying following your advice.

Comment: hi, my command is "ifort -o out eigen.f90 -mkl" while mkl is calling lapack. this command can be successfully run however when I wanted to manipulate the results using "./out" I got "segmentation fault(core dumped)". I appended "-debug""-traceback" without anything changing.Am i missing something?

Comment: (1) where do you get the `inverse` subroutine from? (2) the command would be `ifort -debug -traceback -check bounds -o out eigen.f90 -mkl`, then when crashing, it should print a stacktrace to stderr, which should appear in the output if you run `./a.out` after "segmentation fault(core dumped)"

Comment: inverse subroutine is attached after main program in the same file. I entered the command like you wrote here and it comes out "-bash: ifort　-debug: command not found"

Comment: and i'm still wondering why segmentation fault occurs when the size of matrix is just 900*900. It shouldn't happen because the computer has 64G memory. And if the code is wrong, how to explain that when the size of matrix is less than 297, the code can be run successfully. I think this is the point but without any idea how to explain it.

Comment: please also post the invert subroutine then

Comment: i posted it. In fact, I checked it before without finding mistakes. And to examine the problem is definition of A and B or not, I tried to define A and B to be unit matrix, still segmentation fault occured.

Comment: Like ifort -heap -array -o out eigen.f90 -mkl? This couldn't work....and by "not use automatic arrays", how? it's in subroutine...Should I use allocate command?

Comment: i updated my code using allocate command in subroutine and it did work to some extent. Limit of N is raised from 296 to 418. It seems you're right. Still, could you please teach me how to "not use automatic arrays"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: With 'not using automatic arrays', I meant using allocatable arrays, and then allocating the stuff inside the subroutine, just like you did now. I think I clearly wrote `-heap-arrays` option and not `-heap -array` which you imply, is that the source of your problem?

Comment: Yes. Problem solved!! What a fool I was!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Typical causes of segmentation fault in Fortran are accessing an array beyond its declared size or inconsistencies between actual arguments in the caller and the dummy arguments of the called procedure.  You might find a case of the first problem by turning on runtime error checking, especially subscript checking.   The second can be found by the compiler when all of your routines have explicit interfaces.  The easiest way is to have your procedures in modules and `use` the modules.  This enables the compiler to check consistency of arguments.